# Server 18.04 won't boot, likely bad package upgrade

Tags: boot, apt, server, initramfs

Summary:
update-initramfs fails, can't reinstall it, can't boot server

Details:
Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS ends up with something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBoxu.jpg) from [Ubuntu server crashes on boot "end trace 3b4c21cd8473b17e"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985050/ubuntu-server-crashes-on-boot-end-trace-3b4c21cd8473b17e).

I can use a 16.04.2 .iso to offer me "Rescue a broken system" in a simple GUI:

- Network configuration succeeds

  - I can see it succeeding with "IPv6" and "DHCP" stuff although I don't know the commands it's running
- it recognizes the encrypted volume at `/dev/sdb5` and lets me open it
- then lets me use `/dev/ubuntuserver-vg/root` as the root file system
- recognizes separate `/boot` partition and lets me mount it
- "`grub-install /dev/sdb1` failed" if I try "Reinstall GRUB boot loader"

  - `fdisk -l` puts boot flag on `/dev/sdb1`
- lets me execute a shell with installer environment with `/dev/ubuntuserver-vg/root` mounted on `/target`
- `chroot /target` works
- `df -h | grep boot` says `236M 96M 128M 43% /boot`
- `apt list --installed | grep linux-image` says `linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 4.15.0-66.75 amd64 [installed]`

If I try `apt upgrade --fix-missing` I get

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-66-generic
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 1: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: getopt: not found
W: non-GNU getopt
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-66-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

## Edit 1:

- Thanks to @Rega, I interpreted the messages as missing commands, looked on another Ubuntu system for the package that supplied that command with `dpkg -S <command>` and then reinstalled that package and tried again. There were many broken packages.

After tackling as many as I could, I try to restart but get

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found. Try passing init=option to kernel.
```

The only questions I see don't help:

- Secure boot is not my issue ([Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found. Try passing init=option to kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317521/kernel-panic-not-syncing-no-init-found-try-passing-init-option-to-kernel))
- I don't want to reinstall unless forced to ([Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found. Try passing init=option to kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317521/kernel-panic-not-syncing-no-init-found-try-passing-init-option-to-kernel))
- I don't have dual boot (["Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found. Try passing init = option to kernel" after installing Ubuntu with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362437/kernel-panic-not-syncing-no-init-found-try-passing-init-option-to-kernel))
- I didn't use PenDrive, UNetBootin, etc. (["Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found. Try passing init = option to kernel" after installing Ubuntu with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362437/kernel-panic-not-syncing-no-init-found-try-passing-init-option-to-kernel))
- I can successfully run `update-initramfs -u` from within `chroot /target`
- `update-grub` seems to work although it does seem to share one error `grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.  done`

  - I updated `device.map` to have one line: `(hd0) /dev/disk/by-id/<my /dev/sdb hard drive>`

Sorry, I don't know where is the right forum for this type of overly detailed problem.

I'm totally stuck and would love to be able to boot the server again.

Some questions I've looked at (among many others):

- [My Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS won't boot up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156869/my-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts-wont-boot-up)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044620/ubuntu-18-04-wont-boot)
- [Ubuntu 18.04; Won't Boot After Shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355544/ubuntu-18-04-wont-boot-after-shutdown)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222753/ubuntu-18-04-wont-boot-after-updates)

Answer (score 1):

> /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 1: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: getopt: not found

you seem to not have *getopt* which is a utility that is used to parse command-line options. Check if its in a working state and reconfigure the debs.

> installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

The post-install script for the initramfs-tools package on Ubuntu systems is typically named initramfs-tools.postinst, and it is located in the /var/lib/dpkg/info directory.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which of these "getopt" packages I should reinstall (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=getopt). I've tried removing and reinstalling `initramfs-tools` and `initramfs-tools-core`, are you suggesting I check if the file is in that directory? What if it's not there?

Comment: Glad it helped a bit, did you try to reinstall systemd too(because init)? Dependency and packages issue can be tedious to fix manually and you could have missed some still. I would create my own local repo that has all the debs from the version you are using and upgrade the system from there to sync it with fresh.